# Error while creating iOS Developer CSR for iOS

Tags: ios, openssl, certificate

I am trying to generate a certificate request for an iOS Developer certificate. I get the error below (`Unknown option CN=...`). I am able to generate the private key just fine, it is the next step - generating the cert request that is failing.

```
openssl req -new -key privatekey.key -out  CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest \
    -subj “/emailAddress=myaddress@yahoo.com, CN=MyAccountName, C=US”
```

Results in:

```
Unknown Option CN=MyAccountName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you have formated your request is incorrect.

Use `/` to separate subject information. Use `'` instead of `"`

`openssl req -new -key serverkey.pem  -out CertificateSigningRequest.certSigningRequest -subj '/emailAddress=myaddress@yahoo.com/CN=MyAccountName/C=US'`

Comment: Perfect! I still had to use double quotes - but the / was what was missing. Thanks!